# How to avoid PMD DD anomaly int this case?

Tags: java, pmd

I get PMD, DD anomaly in this code. If I do not initialize port as null then it gives compile time error while  returning the value. Is there is a way to get this code pass through PMD?
PMD is a static code analyzer tool. PMD defines DD anomaly as "A recently defined variable is redefined".

public static Port getPort(String tn) {

```
            Port port = null;
            try {

                 if{

                    String response = invokeWebService(url);
                    if (response == null || response.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        logger.error("", "System Error: Response is empty");
                    } 
                    else {
                        //DD anomaly here
                        port = parseFibResponse( response);
                    }
                } else {
                    port = setOntValues();
                }
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("", "PORT from web service: " + port);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                logger.error("", "System Error: "+ e.getMessage());
            }
            return port;
        }
```

Comment: it should not compile. A else block follows a try block... What is DD anomaly ? Give details.

Comment: Per the PMD rules, it's probably because you defined port as null earlier.
Also, consider using a logging framework which allows you to add formatted messages, i.e. logger.debug("", "Port from web service: {}",port), which ensures you don't need ugly isdebugenabled() (and really, 99,9999% of the time it's premature optimization, so you shouldn't anyway)

Comment: @KoosGadellaa Thank you very much for the logger advice. But how do we avoid this? Considering i have many null checks in the code given to me and i am running this tool to remove the violations. But how do i get away with this one?

Comment: I'm guessing remove the `= null` from the original statement.